# How to pass a Django url in AJAX?

Tags: django, ajax

I'm trying to pass a Django URL in ajax after I get the data from the views.py but i get a page not found when I do so :

```
data.forEach((item) => {
                var url = "{% url 'delete_user' 1 %}".replace('1', item.id);
               tableBody.innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+item.username+'</td><td>'+ item.first_name+'</td><td>'+item.last_name+'</td><td>'+item.email+
                   '</td><td><a href='+url+'><i class="fa fa-trash btn  btn-danger"></i></a></td>' +
                   '<td><a href="{% url \'admin_edit_profile\''+ item.id +'%}"><i class="fa fa-edit btn  btn-warning"></i></a></td></td></tr>'
            });
```

i've Tried this i saw it somewhere here :

```
var url = "{% url 'delete_user' 1 %}".replace('1', item.id);
```

but it doesn't seem to work the error i get :

```
Not Found: /admin_users/{% url 'delete_user'   item.id  %}

[12/Jun/2021 11:04:23] "GET /admin_users/%7B%%20url%20'delete_user'%20%20%20item.id%20%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 7099
```

Comment: I don't get it, why are you trying to use javascript to read django templates, by the time javascript sees it, the url will be already rendered to the actual value. In views file, i would use the reverse function, in javascript i will select the element and read the href attribute?

Comment: Are you doing this in a html template or a separate js file?

Comment: im doing it in a js file

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace in another line:

```
var django_url = "{% url 'delete_user' 1 %}"
var url = django_url.replace('1', item.id);
```

Because Django loads all the template variables at first. Then javascript can be used to modify those static variables.

Comment: i did and it's not working still page not found :  this is the url im getting                       http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_users/%7B%